# Return a value of dictionary where a variable is inbetween keys or values

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some data that I think would work best as a dictionary or JSON. The data has an initial category, a, b...z, and five bands within each category.

What I want to be able to do is give a function a category and a value and for the function to return the corresponding band.

I tried to create a dictionary like this where the values of each band are the lower threshold i.e. for category a, Band 1 is between 0 and 89:

```
bandings = {
    'a' :
        {
          'Band 1' : 0,
          'Band 2': 90,
          'Band 3': 190,
          'Band 4': 420,
          'Band 5': 500
        },
    'b' : 
        {
          'Band 1' : 0,
          'Band 2': 500,
          'Band 3': 1200,
          'Band 4': 1700,
          'Band 5': 2000
        }
}
```

So if I was to run a function:

`lookup_band(category='a', value=100)`

it would return 'Band 3' as 100 is between 90 and 189 in category a

I also experimented with settings keys as ranges but struggled with how to handle a range of > max value in Band 5.

I can change the structure of the dictionary or use a different way of referencing the data.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your data a little bit differently (using sorted lists instead of dictionaries) and use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module. For example:

```
from bisect import bisect

bandings = {
    'a': [0, 90, 190, 420, 500],
    'b': [0, 500, 1200, 1700, 2000]
}

def lookup_band(bandings, band, value):
    return 'Band {}'.format(bisect(bandings[band], value))

print(lookup_band(bandings, 'a', 100))      # Band 2
print(lookup_band(bandings, 'b', 1700))     # Band 4
print(lookup_band(bandings, 'b', 9999))     # Band 5
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! I've never seen bisect before